# Compare two values coming from diferent queries

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a local dashboard where I see data from my software. I have a function which tells me the total of Active Users in real time.

I'm trying to create a function which let's me know the the record of online users, what I want is to get the number of active users, then get the number of the record, compare them and if the number of active users is higher then it would send a query to update the value of the record.

The function is getting all values but it is not updating the record.

This is the function:

```
function recordUsers($conn)
    {
        $resultAU = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM activeUsers");
        $AU_row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($resultAU);

        $resultRU = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM recordUsers");

        $RU_r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultRU);

        if($AU_row_cnt > $RU_r)
        {
            mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE recordUsers SET num = ".$AU_row_cnt."");
        }

        $new_resultRU = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM recordUsers");

        $new_RU_r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($new_resultRU);

        return $new_RU_r['num'];
    }
```

Comment: You realize that you'd be updating your entire database without a WHERE clause, right?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes I know, the table "recordUsers" only has one row, that's why I didn't use a WHERE clause, because I won't be changing any other data

Comment: Ah ok. I wasn't sure. I need to be certain that that was what you wanted to do; all is well :) Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner No problem, I understand your concern, so no worries :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

```php
if($AU_row_cnt > $RU_r)
```

`$RU_r` is an array so the test here would result in an error,

try instead

```php
if($AU_row_cnt > $RU_r['num'])
```

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid because I totally forgot to try that, but still remembered it in the return I had to do it. Thank you :)

Comment: You should avoid using double quotes when not in this context. So when you're not evaluating a variable inside, you should be wrapping your string in single quotes for PHP's interpreter to be faster.

Comment: Also note "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recordUsers" would also speed up your query :)

Comment: @TylerMiles I normally use single quotes instead if I'm messing with a string. I tried with the "```SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table```" but it gives the amount of rows and I only have one row in that table, and what I want to get/update is the value on that row

Comment: I see, my mistake. The count should be on the activeUsers table query. The aggregate functions built into mysql will typically speed up your queries. I'm no expert on them, but here's a list for everyone who comes across this https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-in-mysql.php